# Circle continuously duplicating and glitching in scene

Tags: javafx, bluej

I'm trying to make a 2D version of [Universe Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_Sandbox). I was just starting on coding the gravitational effect on the planets; but once I tested the code, a couple glitches started happening. One of the glitches was whenever I dragged a planet over another planet before placing it. Part of the object would disappear and then reappear once I did it again. Also, the planets position won't update unless I move the group containing the planets. Last, whenever the planets are moving while I am not moving the camera, the planets keep cloning themselves, but part of their clone has a chunk missing from them. I'm pretty sure the place where this could potentially be fixed is either in the `SandBox` class or the `Planet` class; I put markers to indicate where the classes start. Here is the code:

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This class holds the universal variables and objects for Universal Sandbox
 */
public class GroupCode extends Application{
    public static Text text = new Text(10, 20, "");
    public static Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    private static double ox = p.x;
    private static double oy = p.y;
    protected static double x = 0;
    protected static double y = 0;
    public static boolean A = false;
    public static boolean D = false;
    public static boolean W = false;
    public static boolean S = false;
    public static boolean mouseMoving = false;
    /**Universal Group**/
    public static Group MainGroup = new Group(text);
    /**Universal Scene**/
    public static Scene MainScene = new Scene(MainGroup);
    /**Static stage from param stage in method start**/
    public static Stage MainStage;
    /**Creates stage**/
    @Override public void start(Stage stage){
        text.setViewOrder(-1);
        text.setFill(Color.GOLD);
        MainScene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(MainScene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        //System.out.println("---");
        
    //  Dont reference stage before this point
        
        stage.show();
        MainStage = stage;
        
        Editor.addToolBar();
        
        ColorChooser.show();
        
        MainScene.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                x = e.getSceneX();
                y = e.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        
        MainScene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(KeyEvent e){
                switch(e.getCode().toString()){
                    case "A" : A = true; break;
                    case "D" : D = true; break;
                    case "W" : W = true; break;
                    case "S" : S = true;
                }
            }
        });
        
        MainScene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(KeyEvent e){
                switch(e.getCode().toString()){
                    case "A" : A = false; break;
                    case "D" : D = false; break;
                    case "W" : W = false; break;
                    case "S" : S = false;
                }
            }
        });
        
        /*
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                if(ox == p.x && oy == p.y) mouseMoving = false;
                else mouseMoving = true;
                p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                ox = p.x;
                oy = p.y;
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();*/
    }
    
    public static double getHeight(){
        if(MainStage.isFullScreen()) return MainStage.getHeight();
        return MainStage.getHeight() - 28;
    }
    
    public static double getWidth(){
        return MainStage.getWidth();
    }
}

class SandBox{
    public static Group Objects = new Group();
    public static double cameraX = 1000000000;
    public static double cameraY = 1000000000;
    public static double xMotion = 0;
    public static double yMotion = 0;
    public static double planetX = 0;
    public static double planetY = 0;
    
    public static void start(){
        
        GroupCode.MainGroup.getChildren().add(Objects);
        
        Objects.setViewOrder(10);
        
        Graph.start();
        Objects.getChildren().add(Graph.GraphGroup);
        Graph.GraphGroup.setViewOrder(11);
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                if(GroupCode.A) xMotion -= .05;
                if(GroupCode.D) xMotion += .05;
                if(GroupCode.W) yMotion -= .05;
                if(GroupCode.S) yMotion += .05;
                if(xMotion > 0) xMotion -= .025;
                else if(xMotion < 0) xMotion += .025;
                if(yMotion > 0) yMotion -= .025;
                else if(yMotion < 0) yMotion += .025;
                if(Math.abs(xMotion) < .025) xMotion = 0;
                if(Math.abs(yMotion) < .025) yMotion = 0;
                cameraX += xMotion;
                cameraY += yMotion;
                Objects.setLayoutX(-cameraX);
                Objects.setLayoutY(-cameraY);
                //GroupCode.text.setText("CameraX: " + cameraX + "\nCameraY: " + cameraY + "\nOutput: " + (-((int)(-SandBox.cameraX - 5000) / 10000 * 10000)));
                //GroupCode.text.setText("CameraX: " + cameraX + "\nCameraY: " + cameraY + "\nXMotion: " + xMotion + "\nYMotion: " + yMotion);
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
    }
}

class ColorBar
{
    private Point p;
    private Rectangle barIndicator = new Rectangle(-5, -15, 10, 30);
    private LinearGradient gradient;
    private Color color;
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(-100, -10, 200, 20);
    private Group group = new Group(rect, barIndicator);
    private double value = 0;
    private double minimumValue;
    private double maximumValue;
    private boolean pressed = false;
    private boolean hover = false;
    private double width = 100;
    private double height = 10;
    public ColorBar(LinearGradient LG, double minValue, double maxValue){
        minimumValue = minValue;
        maximumValue = maxValue;
        barIndicatorTimeline();
        barIndicator.setFill(Color.GREY);
        gradient = LG;
        rect.setFill(LG);
        value = ((barIndicator.getLayoutX() + width) / (2 * width)) * (maximumValue - minimumValue) + minimumValue;
    }
    
    public ColorBar(Color c, double minValue, double maxValue){
        minimumValue = minValue;
        maximumValue = maxValue;
        barIndicatorTimeline();
        barIndicator.setFill(Color.GREY);
        color = c;
        rect.setFill(c);
    }
    
    public void barIndicatorTimeline(){
        barIndicator.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                barIndicator.setLayoutX(barIndicator.getLayoutX() + e.getX());
                if(barIndicator.getLayoutX() > width)
                    barIndicator.setLayoutX(width);
                if(barIndicator.getLayoutX() < -width)
                    barIndicator.setLayoutX(-width);
                value = ((barIndicator.getLayoutX() + width) / (2 * width)) * (maximumValue - minimumValue) + minimumValue;
            }
        });
    }
    
    public int getInt(){
        return (int)value;
    }
    
    public double getDouble(){
        return value;
    }
    
    public void setX(double x){
        group.setLayoutX(x);
    }
    
    public void setY(double y){
        group.setLayoutY(y);
    }
    
    public void setWidth(double w){
        width = w;
        rect.setScaleX(width / 100);
    }
    
    public void setHeight(double h){
        height = h;
        rect.setScaleY(height / 10);
    }
    
    public Group group(){
        return group;
    }
}

class Planet{
    public static List<Circle> planets = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    protected Circle body = new Circle(20);
    protected double XM = 0;
    protected double YM = 0;
    private boolean exit = false;
    public Planet(){
        
        GroupCode.MainGroup.getChildren().add(body);
        
        body.setFill(ColorChooser.color.getFill());
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                if(!exit){body.setLayoutX(GroupCode.x);
                    body.setLayoutY(GroupCode.y);}
                else time.stop();
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        
        Timeline time2 = new Timeline();
        time2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++){
                    if(body.equals(planets.get(i))) continue;
                    double distance = Math.pow(distance(planets.get(i).getLayoutX(), planets.get(i).getLayoutY(), body.getLayoutX(), body.getLayoutY()), 2);
                    double X = Math.abs(planets.get(i).getLayoutX() - body.getLayoutX());
                    int XDirection = (int)((planets.get(i).getLayoutX() - body.getLayoutX()) / Math.abs(planets.get(i).getLayoutX() - body.getLayoutX()));
                    double Y = Math.abs(planets.get(i).getLayoutY() - body.getLayoutY());
                    int YDirection = (int)((planets.get(i).getLayoutY() - body.getLayoutY()) / Math.abs(planets.get(i).getLayoutY() - body.getLayoutY()));
                    double ratioX = X / (X + Y);
                    double ratioY = Y / (X + Y);
                    
                    XM += ratioX / distance * XDirection;
                    YM += ratioY / distance * YDirection;
                    
                    body.setLayoutX(body.getLayoutX() + XM);
                    body.setLayoutY(body.getLayoutY() + YM);
                }
            }
        });
        time2.getKeyFrames().add(frame2);
        
        body.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if(!exit){
                    planets.add(body);
                    time2.playFromStart();
                    exit = true;
                    body.setLayoutX(body.getLayoutX() + SandBox.cameraX);
                    body.setLayoutY(body.getLayoutY() + SandBox.cameraY);
                    GroupCode.MainGroup.getChildren().remove(body);
                    SandBox.Objects.getChildren().add(body);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
    }
}

/**
 * Pops up a small screen which can help choose a color
 */
class ColorChooser
{
    protected static Rectangle color = new Rectangle(150, -10, 20, 20);
    private static Rectangle exit = new Rectangle(180, -150, 20, 20);
    private static Rectangle dragArea = new Rectangle(-150, -150, 350, 20);
    private static Rectangle BG = new Rectangle(-150, -150, 350, 250);
    private static Group ColorGroup = new Group(BG, dragArea, exit, color);
    private static boolean start = true;
    
    private static ColorBar CBRed;
    private static ColorBar CBGreen;
    private static ColorBar CBBlue;
    
    private static double ox = 0;
    private static double oy = 0;
    
    private static void run(){
        BG.setFill(Color.DARKGREY);
        dragArea.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        exit.setFill(Color.DARKRED);
        color.setStrokeWidth(2);
        ColorGroup.setLayoutX(300);
        ColorGroup.setLayoutY(300);
        
        Stop[] stops1 = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.RED)};
        LinearGradient LG1 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops1);
        CBRed = new ColorBar(LG1, 0, 255);
        CBRed.setY(-50);
        
        Stop[] stops2 = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.GREEN)};
        LinearGradient LG2 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops2);
        CBGreen = new ColorBar(LG2, 0, 255);
        
        Stop[] stops3 = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.BLUE)};
        LinearGradient LG3 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops3);
        CBBlue = new ColorBar(LG3, 0, 255);
        CBBlue.setY(50);
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                color.setFill(Color.rgb(CBRed.getInt(), CBGreen.getInt(), CBBlue.getInt()));
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        
        GroupCode.MainStage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                ox = e.getSceneX(); oy = e.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        
        dragArea.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if(ox == 0){ ox = e.getSceneX(); oy = e.getSceneY(); }
                ColorGroup.setLayoutX(ColorGroup.getLayoutX() + (e.getSceneX() - ox));
                ColorGroup.setLayoutY(ColorGroup.getLayoutY() + (e.getSceneY() - oy));
                ox = e.getSceneX();
                oy = e.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        
        exit.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                exit.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        });
        
        exit.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                exit.setFill(Color.DARKRED);
            }
        });
        
        exit.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                hide();
            }
        });
        
        ColorGroup.getChildren().addAll(CBRed.group(), CBGreen.group(), CBBlue.group());
    }
    
    public static void show(){
        if(start) run();
        start = false;
        
        try{Editor.EditorGroup.getChildren().add(ColorGroup);} catch(Exception ie){}
    }
    
    public static void hide(){
        Editor.EditorGroup.getChildren().remove(ColorGroup);
    }
}

class Button{
    private static int position = 0;
    private Event event;
    private int p = 0;
    private EventHandler e;
    private Rectangle box = new Rectangle(-20, -20, 40, 40);
    private Group group = new Group(box);
    public Button(Shape s){
        p = position;
        position++;
        box.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREY);
        
        s.setFill(Color.GREY);
        
        group.getChildren().add(s);
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                group.setLayoutX(GroupCode.getWidth() / 2 + (p * 40));
                group.setLayoutY(GroupCode.getHeight() - 40);
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        
        group.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent et){
                e.handle(event);
            }
        });
        
        Editor.EditorGroup.getChildren().add(group);
    }
    
    public void event(EventHandler e){
        this.e = e;
    }
}


/**
 * Allows the user to manipulate the scene easily
 */
class Editor{
    
    private static Text sCText = new Text("Select Color");
    private static Rectangle sCBox = new Rectangle(-40, -20, 80, 40);
    private static Group selectColorButton = new Group(sCBox, sCText);
    
    private static Rectangle topBar = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 80);
    public static Group topGroup = new Group(topBar);
    
    private static Rectangle leftBar = new Rectangle(0, 0, 80, 0);
    public static Group leftGroup = new Group(leftBar);
    
    public static Group EditorGroup = new Group();
    public static void addToolBar(){
        
        sCText.setFont(Font.font("", FontWeight.BOLD, 10));
        sCText.setLayoutX(-sCText.getLayoutBounds().getCenterX());
        sCText.setLayoutY(-sCText.getLayoutBounds().getCenterY());
        sCBox.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        selectColorButton.setLayoutX(40);
        
        selectColorButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                ColorChooser.show();
            }
        });
        
        topBar.setFill(Color.DARKGREY);
        leftBar.setFill(Color.DARKGREY);
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                topGroup.setLayoutY(GroupCode.getHeight() - 80);
                topBar.setWidth(GroupCode.getWidth());
                leftBar.setHeight(GroupCode.getHeight());
                selectColorButton.setLayoutY(GroupCode.getHeight() / 2);
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        
        EditorGroup.getChildren().addAll(topGroup, leftGroup, selectColorButton);
        GroupCode.MainGroup.getChildren().add(EditorGroup);
        
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(-2.5, -15, 5, 30);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(-2.5, -15, 5, 30);
        r2.setRotate(90);
        
        SandBox.start();
        
        Button b = new Button(Shape.union(r1, r2));
        b.event(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                new Planet();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Graph{
    public static Group verticalGroup = new Group();
    public static Group horizontalGroup = new Group();
    public static Group GraphGroup = new Group(verticalGroup, horizontalGroup);
    public static void start(){
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            Line line = new Line(-5000 + i * 500, -5000, -5000 + i * 500, 5000);
            line.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
            horizontalGroup.getChildren().add(line);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            Line line = new Line(-5000, -5000 + i * 500, 5000, -5000 + i * 500);
            line.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
            verticalGroup.getChildren().add(line);
        }
        
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                for(int i = -10; i < 10; i++){
                    ((Line)verticalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setStartY((i * 500) - ((int)((i * 500 - SandBox.cameraY)) / 10000 * 10000) + 5000);
                    ((Line)verticalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setEndY((i * 500) - ((int)((i * 500 - SandBox.cameraY)) / 10000 * 10000) + 5000);
                    ((Line)verticalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setLayoutX(SandBox.cameraX);
                }
                for(int i = -10; i < 10; i++){
                    ((Line)horizontalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setStartX((i * 500) - ((int)((i * 500 - SandBox.cameraX)) / 10000 * 10000) + 5000);
                    ((Line)horizontalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setEndX((i * 500) - ((int)((i * 500 - SandBox.cameraX)) / 10000 * 10000) + 5000);
                    ((Line)horizontalGroup.getChildren().get(i + 10)).setLayoutY(SandBox.cameraY);
                }
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for providing the complete example. But i think you can further minimize it by removing the unnecessary code  (like.. the color box, bar.. etc). Also i think you dont need to declare variables as static. Anyway i am still trying to understand the functionality...

Comment: One thing i really dont understand is the excessive use of Timeline. You dont to use timeline for everything...i.e, to continously update the nodes which are pretty much fixed (color of box, graph lines.. etc). You can use listeners if you want to update any of their properties.

Comment: I will strongly suggest you to go through some tutorials about layouts. Group is not the only layout node that exists. Now I see why you excessively rely on Timeline to update the layouts. If you effectively use the layout nodes (HBox, VBox, StackPane...) you can easily get rid 50% of this code.

Comment: I'm wary of using `java.awt` classes  in this context. I cited a likely inspiration for your project; please update as needed.